# Creating a diagram in cloudformation of my EC2's

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to figure out a way to make a json template of my VPC on aws. It seems to only let me create a new stack like LAMP to get a json file. I have already built a database, webserver, subnets etc. I'm just trying to show a visual representation of it in webdesigner.

Answer (score 0):

there is an open-source tool called [Former2](https://former2.com/) that  aims to generate a CloudFormation template from your existing AWS resources.

It has also been described in an [official AWS Blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/accelerate-infrastructure-as-code-development-with-open-source-former2/).

After you generate the template, you can upload it in CloudFormation and view the visual representation in the CloudFormation Designer.

Comment: Do you know if Terraform can do this as well?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but Fomer2 supports the following outputs:

- CloudFormation
- Terraform
- CDK V2 (Cfn Primitives) - TypeScript, Python, Java, C#
- Diagram - embedded version of draw.io

Source: https://github.com/iann0036/former2